# Можно ли доверять Google AdWords?

Tags: google-adwords

Можно ли доверять сервису Google AdWords? Они все время просят меня повысить бюджет потому, что, якобы, у меня недостаточно часто показываются объявления, я мог бы повысить эффективность кампании и т.д. А где гарантии, что они не используют что-нибудь типа ботов и не накручивают мою посещаемость?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доверять сервису AdWords можно. С точки зрения долгосрочного бизнеса собственноручная накрутка кликов для владельца сервиса бессмысленна: репутационные издержки и судебные иски потенциально превышают возможные выгоды от накрутки.

А вот доверять рекламным площадкам надо выборочно: владельцы некоторых сайтов вполне могут использовать ботнеты для накрутки кликов. Чтобы определить эффективность контекстной рекламы, надо оценивать конверсию с различных площадок и исключать тех из них, у которых она очень мала, тогда потенциальные накрутки невелики.